# getting source ip scapy

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I am running Ubuntu of VirtualBox (windows host 10 host).
I have installed PyCharm and Scapy package.

I have written a code to print the source IP in packet p

```
print p[IP].src
```

However, I get a red line under the word IP and an error unresolved reference.
But when I run the script it works perfectly meaning the reference was resolved.

I have imported scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
```

What do I need to install/import to get rid of this error?

Thank you,
Or

Comment: Try changing the import statement to `from scapy.all import *`.

Comment: That is what the statement was, I just wrote here the wrong thing. edited

Comment: Can you add more code? If the defined ``packet`` doesn't have an IP header, there wouldn't be a ``src`` field

Comment: There is a check before that the packet contains an ip layer(I wrote that the script works). even if it didn't have it would cause a runtime error not a compilation error.

Comment: Are you saying the pycharm highlights this as a problem, but it actually runs correctly?  That's how I read the question.  If so - this is more a question about your IDE setup than python.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
print p.getlayer(IP).src
```